# Access Laravel project folder in a codeigniter project

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

CodeIgniter project installed in my root directory but I want to install a Laravel project in a sub-directory. How to do it?

When I'm trying to access my sub-directory it's showing 404 not found..

Comment: The same as you would any directory. Laravel runs from it's `public` folder

Comment: Please check http://womelle.com is a codeigniter project and http://womelle.com/community/ is a Laravel project .... Codeigniter Working well but unable to access to the Laravel project ...

Comment: I'm not being funny Hossain, but I did say it runs from the `public` folder - http://womelle.com/community/public/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point your url to the `public` folder in your `Laravel` folder. At the minute, it is pointing to the `root` of the `Laravel` app.

Once you update `http://womelle.com/community` to point to `http://womelle.com/community/public/` without the constant redirect loop you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: @HossainAzad No problem, if you could make this as accepted I would appreciate it :)